# unable to connect firebase using python 3.72

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

if anyone knows how to python 3.7 version connect with firebase.
I 'm using the following code,

```
from firebase import firebase
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://your_storage.firebaseio.com', None)
result = firebase.get('/users', None)
print (result)
```

it gave the following error
ImportError: cannot import name 'firebase' from 'firebase'

Answer (score 13):

I tried this and I too got an error while importing. From what I gather, python-firebase hasn't been updated to be fully compatible with python 3.7 or perhaps this is a rare issue.

What I found was that the firebase module actually had an error as it used python's protected keyword `async` as a filename.

**Here's what fixed the issue for me:**

1. First run the command `python3 -m pip show python-firebase`.
2. From there you should see a path to the pip folder. This could look like `Location: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages`
3. Navigate to that folder and find your "firebase" folder. Once in the folder, rename the `async.py` file to something else, I renamed it to `nasync.py`. Next you should open the __init__.py file and change the import declaration from `from .async import process_pool` to `from .nasync import process_pool` You also have to repeat this in the `firebase.py` file.

Hope this helps :)